# Installing Wine.hq in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, wine, update-manager

> Hi, I'm currently installing Wine.HQ in my Ubuntu Desktop. My problem is this:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ wget -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -

--2021-04-19 21:20:03--  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
Resolving dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)... 199.232.134.217
Connecting to dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)|199.232.134.217|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3220 (3,1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                   100%[===================&gt;]   3,14K  --.-KB/s    in 0,001s  

2021-04-19 21:20:09 (3,80 MB/s) - written to stdout [3220/3220]

OK
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
Hit:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease               
Ign:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-bulds/ubuntu focal InRelease                  
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease 
Hit:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease 
Err:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-bulds/ubuntu focal Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.134.217 443]
Hit:12 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease          
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-bulds/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

> I don't know what i have to do, someone had the same error and know how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you added a eoan/19.10 repository onto a focal/20.04 system. That seems unwise (or useless). For most users, the quite good version of Wine already in the Ubuntu repositories is much easier to install than the method you have chosen.

Comment: *wine-bulds* should be *wine-builds*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***I've fixed it, It works if you do this:***

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-staging
```