# Remove eoan/19.10 repository on to a focal/20.04 System

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, 19.10, repository

> It's just that i said in the title. I have an error, because i tried to install wine, and then, this happens:

```
Hit:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease               
Ign:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-bulds/ubuntu focal InRelease                  
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease 
Hit:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease 
Err:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-bulds/ubuntu focal Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.134.217 443]
Hit:12 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease          
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-bulds/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I did a question here
[Installing Wine.hq in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332551/installing-wine-hq-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: The real problem, as pointed out yesterday, is the typo on 11: `https://dl.winehq.org/wine-bulds/ubuntu`  "builds" lacks an 'i'. The addition of a 19.10 repo is sloppy, and it should be removed, but it's not critical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed to fetch security undermined error \[IP: 91.189.91.38 80\] in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305141/failed-to-fetch-security-undermined-error-ip-91-189-91-38-80-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: No, it doesnt answer my question, but i wanna uninstall it, because when i write `sudo apt update`, i see that everytime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: The repository 'http//archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120194/e-the-repository-http-archive-canonical-com-precise-release-is-not-signed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sources are stored as text files in two places: /etc/apt/sources.list (a file) and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ (a directory containing files)

You can manually *disable* a source in any of those text files by putting a comment mark (#) in front of the line. Here's an example:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy main       // Active
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy main     // Disabled
```

- Open these files in a text editor (like `nano`), not a word processor. [nano instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano)
- These files are owned by root; you must use `sudo`: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

You can *delete* a source by simply deleting the line in the file. If you are unsure if you should disable or delete a source, ask.

---

You can also disable or delete sources using the Software & Updates control panel. Here's an example:

- It's not in *settings* -- find it using your Desktop Search (the little 9-box grid or your <Super> key).

[image: Software & Updates Control Panel]

- Make sure you are looking at the *Other Software* tab.
- *Enable* a disabled source by checking the box.
- *Disable* a source by un-checking it.
- *Delete* a source by highlighting, then clicking 'Remove'

Answer (score 1):

To remove `eoan` from your sources :

```
sudo sed -i '/eoan/d' /etc/apt/sources{,.d/*}.list
```

It will remove the lines with `eoan` under `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.d/*`

Solving the following error:

```
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-bulds/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
```

**A typo** in the URL `wine-bulds`, it should be `wine-builds`. `i` is missing. (mentioned on [@user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332775/remove-eoan-19-10-repository-on-to-a-focal-20-04-system#comment2273535_1332775))

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the file under `/etc/apt/sources.d/` as follows (also remove duplicate urls):

```
 deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

[Installing WineHQ packages](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)